# Attaching flexible bath drain pipe to dwv pvc pipe

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, drain-waste-vent

The drain pipe in the image below came with a bathtub I bought. How is it supposed to attach to regular dwv pvc? The inner diameter is about 1.375 inches, although at the two grooves near the end the diameter is less. Is it supposed to slip over a 1” pvc pipe, and be clamped at the two grooves? It is flexible and the end is also not very rigid.

[image: flexible pipe]